# Encontrar archivos .exe en MS-DOS

Tags: cmd, msdos

¡Muy buenas! Estoy tratando de realizar unos ejercicios de clase con MS-DOS, y en uno de ellos se nos pregunta mediante qué comandos podemos buscar todos los archivos .exe de un directorio de dos maneras diferentes, en este caso, de la siguiente carpeta:

> C:\DOS71

Conozco el método dir `C:\DOS71\*.exe` , pero pese a horas de investigación no encuentro una respuesta clara a mi duda. Si alguien conoce más maneras de realizar esta búsqueda, estaría muy agradecido de conocerlas. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Mira eso solo como referencia.. tu pregunta esta muy bien estructurada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una manera sería:

```
dir *.exe
```

Esta es la sintaxis del comando DIR sí:

```
dir [unidad:][ruta][archivo] [/a[[:]attributos]] [/b] [/c] [/d] [/l] [/n] [/o] [/p] [/q] [/r] [/s] [/t] [/w] [/x] [/4]
```

También puedes dar salida a un archivo o impresora, en vez de por pantalla..

Por archivo sería:

```
dir *.exe > nombreArchivo.txt
```

Por impresora sería:

```
dir *.exe > prn
```

(bueno soy de la vieja escuela y la salida por impresora era así antes, no sé si con las impresoras USB´s sería de la misma forma).

Espero te sirva ... Saludos